# Create new node in Cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra, and I use only one machine to test, how can I create new node, and add it to current cassandra DB ? says I want 1 cluster with 03 nodes inside it.. each node will be a separately Cassandra db or what ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit cassandra.yaml on the node you are adding to the cluster. Basically you should do only a few changes:

1. Make sure that the cluster name is the same as on the existing node.
2. Specify `seeds` property to contain list of 1 item - existing node
3. Provide `initial_token` property so that token distribution across cluster is uniform.

More details might be found here: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted
'configuring multinode cluster'